# Integral approximation project, what integrals should I choose?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

For a highschool project I've been asked to make a scientific investigation of some sort, I chose numerical methods to calculate integrals.
I want to use multiple methods and therefore wonder what integrals I should choose to show the advantages and disadvantages of the different methods.
My current list of methods to try are: Riemann sums, Taylor series and interchanging order of integration and summation (i.e. for the gaussian integral).
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: tanh-sinh quadrature, trapezoidal quadrature, Gaussian quadrature. Try trapezoidal quadrature on periodic integrands and Gaussian functions and see what happens.

Comment: If your scientific investigation into numerical integration is of wider scope than just pure maths then there are various mechanical, electrical and electronic integration devices which will all have different upper limits to the accuracy and precision obtainable (e.g. tipping bucket rain gauge to integrate rainfall, whilst perhaps failing to integrate snowfall as well) . The natural environment will integrate various forms of precipitation for example:  into a snowpack with varying density with depth or alternatively into wide variations in river volume flow rate of water with time.